# How to get file path without extension in Rust?

Tags: rust, filepath, file-extension

Please help me to find an elegant way to get file path without extension; cut off file extension from path or something.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Check the [`Path::file_stem` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.file_stem). You can find an example there. It works at least from Rust 1.6.

Comment: Is there a method which gets the full absolute path before extension, not just the filename?

Comment: do you know the bahaviour if the file name has two extensions like "file.abc.xyz"?

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie the linked docs answer this: it returns "the portion of the file name before the final `.`"

Answer (score 20):

Using the [`Path::with_extension("")` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.with_extension) gives you the full path with a possible file extension removed.

Comment: This correctly answers the question, as if the input is a path with intermediate directories, this returns the full path, with the file_stem.